# Move back from archive to inbox

Tags: thunderbird

How in Thunderbird 3 do you move back a mail from Archive to Inbox ?

I've never used 'Bird before, so I'm not sure - does Archive in it works the same way as it does in GMail ?

I presume it doesn't delete any mails frm the Archive at any point in time without my explicit permission ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how your server creates folders. For example, on my GMail account used with Thunderbird 3.0, the e-mails are moved from Inbox to Archives/Year. Note that because GMail uses labels instead of folders, this is a label name and not the folder Year under the folder Archives. On my webhost's e-mail service, it stores them under the folder Year which itself is under the Archives folder.

In answer to your first question, all you have to do is move the folder from the Archives/Year folder to the Inbox. Or on Gmail, you just have to mark it unread and optionally remove the Archives/Year label.

I don't believe Thunderbird deletes any mails from archive, but I'm just going off my own experience.

Comment: Good point. It slipped my mind that under Gmail they are only labels. But it still leaves the question - how do you move mail from arc. to inbox - I haven't seen any "move to inbox" buttons anywhere.

Comment: If you're in Thunderbird, there should be an "Archives" list in the tree selector on the left. Click on that, click on your account, click on the appropriate year. Find the e-mail you want to move back and right-click. Use the Move To->Account->Inbox option. :)

Comment: Thought there would be something like a explicit button (gmail like) for that. In any case, drag and drop solved the problem.